# How to add the Project root to the localhost path

Tags: asp.net

My asp.net project, currently runs from **http://localhost:51143/default.aspx**

Is there anyway, I could include the root to this like **http://localhost:51143/TOrders/default.aspx** The reason I want to do this is because the  URls that get called on the menu click events refer to "TOrders/Reports/aaa.aspx and so on and in production it would refer to intranet/TOrders/Reports/aaa.aspx and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need [HttpRequest.ApplicationPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) property
or [HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationvirtualpath.aspx) property.

Also useful for building virtual paths is [VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx) class.

**EDIT:**

Try to copy your project into a subfolder of you web root, for eg. in IIS:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\  (or what you set)
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\
```

Now in IIS Managment Console, in your Default Web, you create a new 'Application'. Either you upgrade the existing folder or you create a virtual new one to your folder.

Then select a virtual path (TOrders) and set the physical path. There you will also set the AppPool if you have .NET 4, or select the runtime if you have 2.0/3.5 on IIS6.x. Try the highest version first...

Go to localhost/TOrders/

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Can this be done non-programatically ?

Comment: Thank you. I did as you explained. But in IIS 7, when I try to browse localhost/TOrders/default.aspx, it displays default.aspx of the intranet website http://mytsystem/default.aspx. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to intercept every request in **Application_BeginRequest** method in **Global.asax**. 
There you can create a rule to remove **TOrders/** from the beginning. Try something like this:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.RawUrl.StartsWith("TOrders/"))
        Server.Transfer(Request.RawUrl.Substring(8));
}
```

This may not the nicest solution, but it should be enough to give you idea what to do.

**Edit:**

Since you have web project (not a web site), you can set **virtual path** of your project. I think this is what you are looking for.

If you are using VS2010, in Solution explorer right click on your project and chose **Properties**, then on **Web** tab, in Servers section, change **virtual path** of your project to **/TOrders/** instead of **/** which is default value. Now you should get **http://localhost:51143/TOrders/default.aspx**